# Inverse of this function.

Tags: functions, set-theory, relations, inverse-function

[image]

Here, I am confused between option C) and D). I really cannot get where's the flaw in D) (Answer given is C).

PS. I don't know what working to show here. I request to not close this question for the same.

Comment: Kindly explain the downvotes so that maybe I can fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take as example $X = \{1,2\}$ and $Y = \{0\}$. Then take $d = \{0\}$, yielding $x = X$. Take $a = \{ 1\} \subseteq x$ and compute $f^{-1}(f(a))$. You will see that it will not be $a$.